# Disable alt-checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using alt-checkbox jquery plugin for displaying checkbox.I am not able to disable the alt-checkbox.For disabling chekbox I have used following properties.

```
$("#MyId").prop("disabled",true);
```

http://alt-checkbox.starikovs.com/ - this reference url for alt-checkbox.

Comment: have you tried $("#MyId").prop("disabled","disabled");?

Comment: I've had a look through both the documentation and the source code for alt-checkbox and it appears to not have a method to disable it.  I'd suggest looking for a plugin that isn't so basic.

Comment: Try it with `.prop({disabled: true});` and see if it works. Like @Archer mentioned,  i too couldn't find anything on this plugin to support disabled checkbox. @BhushanKawadkar what is wrong with `.prop("disabled",true)`?

Comment: This plugin use an anchor tag to render a faked checkbox. You have to prevent click on this anchor in some way too, as using CSS property `pointer-events: none;` on modern browsers or set an element in front to support these odler browsers. e.g: `$("#MyId").prop("disabled",true).prev('a').css('pointer-events','none');`  http://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: I was just wondering if `#MyId` is the id of your original checkbox.  If it is,  you will have to target the new checkbox created with this plugin.  play with the HTML in firebug.  I added and attribute of `disabled="true"` to the `<a>` created by this plugin it worked.  So,  probably,  you are targeting wrong element(input that is already hidden).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/107/

I used the sample code provided in the demo of `alt-checkbox`

Javascript:

```
var make = (function () {//Sample code from demo starts.
jQuery("#checkbox1").altCheckbox({
    outlineUnchecked: false,
    sizeClass: "small"
});
jQuery("#checkbox2").altCheckbox();
jQuery("#checkbox3").altCheckbox({
    sizeClass: "big"
});
});
make();//Sample code from demo ends

//Actual code begins
$(document).on('click', '.alt-checkbox', function (e) {
    var a = $(this);
    var cb = a.nextAll('input[type="checkbox"]:first');
    if (cb.attr('disabled')) {
        console.log('doing nothing');
        e.stopPropagation();
        a.removeClass('checked');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<h1>alt-checkbox demo</h1>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1">Check Me! I'm small.</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" disabled="disabled">
<label for="checkbox2">Check Me! I'm medium.</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
<label for="checkbox3">Check Me! I'm big.</label>
<div> 
   <a href="javascript:make()">make</a>
   <a href="javascript:jQuery('[type=checkbox]').altCheckbox('clear')">clear</a>
</div>
```

Note: You can ignore the `make()` function.
In the second checkbox, I added disabled attribute for testing purpose. You can add the disabled attribute whenever you want to disable the input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple workaround. You have to 'clear' altCheckbox, change the properties and then 'make' them into altCheckboxes again.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function disableMe()
 jQuery('[type=checkbox]').altCheckbox('clear')
 document.getElementById('MyId').checked=false;
 document.getElementById('MyId').disabled=true;
    jQuery("#MyId").altCheckbox({outlineUnchecked:false,sizeClass: "small"});
</script>
```

```html
<h1>alt-checkbox demo</h1>
<input type="checkbox" id="MyId">
<label for="checkbox1">Check Me! I'm small.</label>
<br><br>
<button onclick="disableMe()">disableMe</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the same component, and in these cases we "disable" the click event of the generated anchor element like this:

`$(':checkbox:disabled').prev(".alt-checkbox").off("click");`